# Is there any way to get the arn for a secret manager secret from a secret (or from cdk)?

Tags: aws-cdk

I am looking to get the arn of a secret so I can allow infrastructure I am deploying to have the permissions to get that secret e.g.:

`const secret = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretArn(stack, secretName, secretArn);
 secret.grantRead(CdkBuild);`

In this case to allow a codebuild build to be able to read a secret without me having to pass it in a way which appears in the logs (e.g. echo to file or... etc)

I can get the arn by using the AWS SDK listSecrets call and then iterating until the secretName matches but that is an async call and the value is returned after the cdk has passed the point where it needs the value.

I can get the secret value itself from within cdk e.g. for a github token:

`ghtokenSecret = cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(secretName, {
    jsonField: ghtoken,
 });`

But can see no method/way to get the secret arn such that I can pass the value to my codebuild infrastructure.

Given multiple accounts for multiple environments (dev, sandbox, integration etc) allowing the use of just the SecretName allows me to use the cdk script effectively unchanged vs if using the arn as I have to create the secret for that account (using the same secret name) and then find it's arn and then insert that arn into some config (e.g. cdk.json) for each branch etc. which is potentially a source of failure/error.

Any ideas gladly welcomed

Comment: dont get where you  iterate with listSecrets. Can you show that part of your CDK project? You ve written "AWS SDK" which makes me wonder if this listSecrets is even a part of a CDK project.

Comment: I could not find how to do it inside CDK so was forced to use the standard AWS sdk javascript code from inside my cdk javascript to get the [value]( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html#listSecrets-property) . I was wanting to avoid that and instead be able to get the cdk javascript alone.